# Null pointer exception on Firebase Initialization on Symphony Teleca device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am getting crash report from device S3T7IN (astar-d86). It is a Symphony Teleca device. I cannot find anything about this device on Google.

Crash is null pointer exception on Firebase Initialization .

This is my code

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

private FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_screen);


    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(); //I am getting null pointer exception here
```

This is what I get in dev console

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zzbD(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.brane.radio.PlayScreen.onCreate(PlayScreen.java:168)
```

I'm not sure if I have an issue in my code or if this device has an incompatible version of the OS. Or maybe is firebase bug.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you add **compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.1'** to your **build.gradle**? [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#addremote-config-to-your-app)

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler of course .

Comment: I have a report of the same crash, using Firebase version 9.0.2.

Comment: @jkane001 Perhaps it's a Firebase bug than.

Answer (score -1):

With Firebase version 11.6.0 I faced the same issue, my solution was to downgrade to 10.2.0.